# How can i use <%# Bind("myField") %> from a usercontrol in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

Like the title says, i would like to bind data from my usercontrol to my page's EntityDataSource. I tried this:

in my user control:

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" id="mytxtbox" Text='<%# Bind("myField") %>
```

In my asp page:

```
<% Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="myControl" src="~/MyControl.ascx" %>
...
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDS" runat="server" ....></asp:EntityDataSource
<asp:FormView id="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceId="EDS">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <uc:myControl runat="server" id="customControl"/>
        ...
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <uc:myControl runat="server" id="customControl"/>
        ...
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc:myControl runat="server" id="customControl"/>
        ...
        <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:formview>
```

Using this method, i was able to display my user control's fields properly (with the appropriate content from by database), but i cannot insert/Update data.

Comment: Show us the code you use to INSERT/UPDATE please! :)

Comment: Well..there is not much...the formview is supposed to do it for me isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried detailsview/gridview in VS2010. I use gridview to display and then link it to detailsview by passing value where I can edit/delete records in VS2010.

This can be a big help 
[Click here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-vb)

Also, check this out [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stc0szde%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1 I suggest you to `find` your control on `Page_Init`, so you pass your DataSource (DataTable or other)

```
var control = (UserControl)this.FindControl("id");
control.Property = .....;
```

2 You declare for example an public property  on your control

3 And you bind your control in his code behind.

Nota : If you have grid control in your userControl you can use `ItemDataBound`

Comment: What do you mean by "You bind your control in his code behind"?

Comment: so it would look something like Text='<%# Bind("myProperty") %> or do i have to write something like Text='<%# MyDataObject.Bind("myProperty")%>' ?

Comment: Just <%# Bind("myProperty") %>

Comment: it's not working, or perhaps i'm doing something wrong: I have created a usercontrol named "UC". In that usercontrol, i've set a public property of type EntityDataSource called "DS".In the page_init event of my page, i'm finding this control, and assigning my page's EntityDataSource to my usercontrol's property called "DS" (which's type is EntityDataSource). In my textbox of the usercontrol, i'm setting the text property to '<%# Bind("MyProperty") %>'... Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: it still doesn't work :( Using this method, i don't see how asp will know to put the <%# Bind("myproprerty") %> in the dataItem of my usercontrol...

Comment: if you bind your user control with datas , yes your  user control know his datasource